# String a = "x"; then String x = a.substring(1) Wouldn't there be an error like indexOutOfRange?

Tags: java, string

I am so confused. I thought to use str.substring(1), str has to be at least 2 characters, otherwise there should be index of of bound. But when I typed in, Java doesn't give any error. Why?

Comment: The [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) shows a fine example of that behaviour: `"emptiness".substring(9)` returns `""` (an empty string)

Comment: Because an empty string is still a string. Given `String a = "x";`, then `a.substring(1)` is `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Read the Javadoc:

> **String java.lang.String.substring(int beginIndex)**
>
> Returns a string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the end of this string.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or **larger than the length of this String object**.

Your `beginIndex` is equal to the length of the `String`, so no exception is thrown and an empty `String` is returned.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-

```
IndexOutOfBoundsException - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.
```

It is legal to have the index equal to the length in order to return an empty string.